# Dynamically access request.GET in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to dynamically access `GET` parameters in **Django** template, but it's not working.

URL: `?id=1&name=John`

I've tried something like this:

```
{% for r in request.GET %}
    {% if request.GET.r %}
        {{r}} = {{request.GET.r}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that even if the parameters are set, nothing is returned in the template.

It works though if I do `request.GET.id` or `request.GET.name`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As `request.GET` is a dictionary, you should use `request.GET.items` in the loop ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for)).

```
{% for key, value in request.GET.items %}
    {{key}} = {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with the additional challenge of having multiple values with the same key.

URL: `?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4`

In that case i used the following:

```
{%for key, values in request.GET.lists%}
    {%for value in values%}
        {{value}}  
    {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```